# Problem with PlanarGraphPlot And ConvexHull

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm getting a lot of strange errors when using `PlanarGraphPlot` with a simple list of 11 points.  This is using Mma 9.0.1 64-bit Mac OS X.

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`;
x = {{184978.59580704456`, 77909.66948289984`}, 
     {184978.27815712072`,77909.76595227784`},
     {184978.27082673783`, 77909.74177736834`},
     {184977.5543690799`, 77909.95958192856`},
     {184977.65873976916`, 77910.2913545858`},
     {184977.87393886593`, 77910.32174601014`},
     {184978.3127146399`, 77911.75682671613`},
     {184979.13720817852`, 77911.37094455786`},
     {184979.40459261995`, 77911.34308556134`},
     {184979.6157774594`, 77912.04232488069`},
     {184980.40222282038`, 77911.69604330455`}};
PlanarGraphPlot[x]
```

Errors I get are

```
Mod::indet: Indeterminate expression Mod[-1,0] encountered. >>

Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>

Part::pspec: Part specification Indeterminate is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers. >>

Part::pspec: Part specification {{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,5,6,3,5},{11,10,9,4},{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[8,1]] is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers. >>

Part::pspec: Part specification {{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,5,6,3,5},{11,10,9,4},{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[8,1]] is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers. >>

General::stop: Further output of Part::pspec will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>

Set::shape: Lists {ComputationalGeometry`Private`merge$30945[[ComputationalGeometry`Private`l0$30945]],ComputationalGeometry`Private`merge$30945[[ComputationalGeometry`Private`r0$30945]]} and ComputationalGeometry`Private`insert[{{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,5,6,3,5},{11,10,9,4},{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[{6,{{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,5,6,3,5},{11,10,9,4},{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[8,1]]}]],6,{{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,<<3>>,5},<<1>>,{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[<<1>>]],2,3] are not the same shape. >>

Mod::indet: Indeterminate expression Mod[-1,0] encountered. >>

Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>

General::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Set::shape: Lists {ComputationalGeometry`Private`merge$33935[[ComputationalGeometry`Private`l0$33935]],ComputationalGeometry`Private`merge$33935[[ComputationalGeometry`Private`r0$33935]]} and ComputationalGeometry`Private`insert[{{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,5,6,3,5},{11,10,9,4},{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[{6,{{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,5,6,3,5},{11,10,9,4},{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[8,1]]}]],6,{{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,<<3>>,5},<<1>>,{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[<<1>>]],2,3] are not the same shape. >>

Mod::indet: Indeterminate expression Mod[-1,0] encountered. >>

General::stop: Further output of Mod::indet will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Set::shape: Lists {ComputationalGeometry`Private`merge$35305[[ComputationalGeometry`Private`l0$35305]],ComputationalGeometry`Private`merge$35305[[ComputationalGeometry`Private`r0$35305]]} and ComputationalGeometry`Private`insert[{{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,5,6,3,5},{11,10,9,4},{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[{6,{{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,5,6,3,5},{11,10,9,4},{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[8,1]]}]],6,{{4,2},{1,4,6},{6},{7,2,1},{6,6},{2,<<3>>,5},<<1>>,{},{7,10},{9,7,11},{10,7}}[[<<1>>]],2,3] are not the same shape. >>

General::stop: Further output of Set::shape will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

Removing certain points from the list (like the last one) causes the plot to succeed.

Also this set of points fails to give proper `ConvexHull`

```
y = {{1.8497859580704457`, 0.7790966948289985`},
    {1.8497827815712071`, 0.7790976595227784`},
    {1.8497827082673783`, 0.7790974177736835`},
    {1.849775543690799`, 0.7790995958192857`},
    {1.8497765873976917`, 0.779102913545858`},
    {1.8497787393886593`, 0.7791032174601015`},
    {1.849783127146399`, 0.7791175682671613`},
    {1.8497913720817853`, 0.7791137094455786`},
    {1.8497940459261994`, 0.7791134308556135`},
    {1.849796157774594`, 0.7791204232488069`},
    {1.849804022228204`, 0.7791169604330455`},
    {1.849803552734635`, 0.7791159289575218`},
    {1.8498057134522492`, 0.7791151852825192`},
    {1.8498006729413692`, 0.7790991813917657`},
    {1.8498002121744468`, 0.7790984699581178`},
    {1.8497995890919037`, 0.7790977401058187`},
    {1.8497986151981813`, 0.7790973602143807`},
    {1.8497975924352397`, 0.7790973993547065`},
    {1.8497955957785752`, 0.77909842160827`},
    {1.8497951821355425`, 0.7790997823117062`},
    {1.8497944840038416`, 0.779101624213374`},
    {1.8497934996381435`, 0.7791037516125543`},
    {1.8497920021456453`, 0.779106194441444`},
    {1.849792775326504`, 0.7791094914607818`},
    {1.8497897908134828`, 0.7791098506337076`}}
Graphics@Point@y[[ ConvexHull[y] ]]
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the number of points needs to be even. Add a point, or remove the last one, and the error goes away! You currently have in `x` 11 (odd) number of points. This is a guess based on trial and error.

Comment: @Nasser This is not what I'm seeing.  Removing last point works but removing second point doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I see the same problem here also. Well, it was a guess any way. So there is a bug :)

Comment: cross posted http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/243036?p_p_auth=9IrMv7Cx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers are too big and too close  ... a recipe for numeric disaster. Just translate them to the origin:

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
PlanarGraphPlot[Transpose[Transpose@x - Mean[x]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks.  That works nicely.  Does my `ConvexHull` example have a similar problem?  Translating that to the origin doesn't help.  I get all the input points back from `ConvexHull`

Comment: @Kartik For similar reasons `p = 10^6 Transpose[Transpose@y - Mean[y]];convexHull = ConvexHull[p];PlanarGraphPlot[p, convexHull]`

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
PlanarGraphPlot[TranslationTransform[- Mean @ x] @ x]
```

[image]